# Removing items corresponding to nan in one list from another list

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For regressions in sklearn, I have a list `x` and a list `y`. Unfortunately these lists have blanks/NaN. A NaN crashes any analysis, so I need to remove each NaN and its corresponding number in the other list (to keep the relationship between `x[0]` and `y[0]`, etc.)

What is an elegant way to find this? Is there an alternative to loops?

Comment: I guess the lengths are the same right?

Comment: @n9code right. Initially they are the same. If I remove a nan in one list I must also remove the one with the same index in the other list, so the lengths will always be the same.

Comment: are the `'nan'` values string `'nan'` or Python `None`?

Comment: @n9code `nan` may mean Not A Number

Comment: Yes, not a number, the type is not string

Comment: ok then, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, using Python built-in function [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [**`filter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def filter_nans(x, y):
    filtered = filter(lambda o: not math.isnan(o[0]) and not math.isnan(o[1]), zip(x, y))    
    return [el[0] for el in filtered], [el[1] for el in filtered]
```

So for example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, 8]
y = [10, 'not a number', 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]

x, y = filter_nans(x, y)

>>> x
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
>>> y
[10, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80]
```

Comment: I think you might need to filter out the elements that are not numbers (it is not clear if they are strings containing numbers or plain integers).

Comment: Lambda expression should use math.isnan to check whether values are NaN.